# WPF How to reference color resources in other projects

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I create a custom control library like this：
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YWQJP.png)

Generic.xaml：

```
<ResourceDictionary
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="/KiwiWPFControl;component/Themes/KiwiButton.xaml"/>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="/KiwiWPFControl;component/Themes/KiwiColor.xaml"/>
</ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
```

And I create a demo project:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/622Gr.png)

App.xaml:

```
<Application x:Class="KiwiWPFDemo.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:KiwiWPFDemo"
         StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/LayUI.Wpf;component/Themes/Default.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/KiwiWPFControl;component/Themes/Generic.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:KiwiWPFDemo"
    xmlns:lvc="clr-namespace:LiveCharts.Wpf;assembly=LiveCharts.Wpf"
    xmlns:Lay="clr-namespace:LayUI.Wpf.Controls;assembly=LayUI.Wpf"
    xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:KiwiWPFControl.Controls;assembly=KiwiWPFControl" x:Class="KiwiWPFDemo.MainWindow"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Height="800" Width="1000">
<Grid>
    <Controls:KiwiButton Content="KiwiButton" FontSize="15" Width="100" Height="50" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="108,191,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <Button Background="{StaticResource HiGreenBrush}" Content="KiwiButton" FontSize="15" Width="100" Height="50" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="108,300,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
</Grid>
```

The code

```
Background="{StaticResource HiGreenBrush}"
```

reports ： Unable to resolve resource "HiGreenBrush"

Modify App.xaml as follows：

```
<Application x:Class="KiwiWPFDemo.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:KiwiWPFDemo"
         StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/LayUI.Wpf;component/Themes/Default.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/KiwiWPFControl;component/Themes/Generic.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/KiwiWPFControl;component/Themes/KiwiColor.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

No change happens

Modify MainWindow.xaml as follows：:

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:KiwiWPFDemo"
    xmlns:lvc="clr-namespace:LiveCharts.Wpf;assembly=LiveCharts.Wpf"
    xmlns:Lay="clr-namespace:LayUI.Wpf.Controls;assembly=LayUI.Wpf"
    xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:KiwiWPFControl.Controls;assembly=KiwiWPFControl" x:Class="KiwiWPFDemo.MainWindow"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Height="800" Width="1000">
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/KiwiWPFControl;component/Themes/KiwiColor.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Controls:KiwiButton Content="KiwiButton" FontSize="15" Width="100" Height="50" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="108,191,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <Button Background="{StaticResource HiGreenBrush}" Content="KiwiButton" FontSize="15" Width="100" Height="50" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="108,300,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
</Grid>
```

The error is gone

How should I reference the KiwiColor.xaml in App.xaml?

KiwiColor.xaml:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
<Color x:Key="HiGreen">#FF00AAA6</Color>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="HiGreenBrush">#FF00AAA6</SolidColorBrush>
<Color x:Key="ButtonStepColor">#FF00BB86</Color>
<Color x:Key="HiGreenGradientStep1">#FF00BB88</Color>
<Color x:Key="HiGreenGradientStep2">#FF00AA88</Color>
<Color x:Key="HiBlack">#FF0E0E0E</Color>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="HiBlackBrush">#FF0E0E0E</SolidColorBrush>
<Color x:Key="HiGray">#FFC0C0C0</Color>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="HiGrayBrush">#FFC0C0C0</SolidColorBrush>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ProgressBar.Background" Color="#C0C0C0"/>
<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="HiBackgroundBrush" EndPoint="1,0" StartPoint="0,0" >
    <GradientStop Color="{StaticResource HiGreenGradientStep1}" Offset="0"/>
    <GradientStop Color="{StaticResource HiGreenGradientStep2}" Offset="0.5"/>
    <GradientStop Color="{StaticResource HiGreen}" Offset="1"/>
</LinearGradientBrush>
```

I find the point:

1.The "Output type" of the demo project is "Class Library"

2.The "Build Action" of the demo project is "Page"

Then reports ： The resource "HiGreenBrush" could not be resolved.

I use another program to start the demo project, so it is set to dll.

And I change the demo project as follows:

1.The "Output type" of the demo project is "Windows Application"

2.The "Build Action" of the demo project is "ApplicationDefinition"

The error is gone.

And this is why @Andy and @mm8 said it should work ok.

How should I reference the KiwiColor.xaml if the demo project is a dll??

Comment: Should work. How is `HiGreenBrush` defined? Does it fail at runtime or design time?

Comment: Not sure what the difference is in what you have.  My version works ok.

Comment: @mm8 KiwiColor.xaml has been posted

Comment: Thanks @Andy
I find the answer when I create another question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75395253/how-to-reference-use-resource-between-multiple-projects-inside-solution/75395469#75395469

Answer (score 0):

I tried replicating this issue.

I have a customcontrol library WpfCustomControlLibrary1 which has my version of kiwibutton in it.

I added a usercontrol library and put a resource dictionary in that.

There's the one brush in that:

```
<SolidColorBrush Color="Green" x:Key="MyGreen"/>
```

I merge it in app.xaml

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/ColourLibrary;component/ColourDictionary.xaml"/>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/WpfCustomControlLibrary1;component/Themes/Generic.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Have a reference to ColourLibrary and WpfCustomControlLibrary1 in my main project.

In there I have a kiwibutton

```
<Button Background="{StaticResource MyGreen}" 
        Content="KiwiButton" FontSize="15" Width="100" Height="50" 
        HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="108,300,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
```

And that works fine for me.

That's one way to implement what you describe.

Ordinarily, I would expect everything that is part of a theme to be in the one theme rather than different projects.

The way custom controls work is rather a complication from that perspective and I rarely use them.  I see the reason to have a custom control at all is if you want to completely re template it depending on various themes. Creating a viable all encompassing theme is a lot of work. Very few clients want a full on switchable theme, in my experience. Cost way too much to develop.

I wonder whether there's something subtly wrong with your resource dictionary merging.

Comment: I moved color up, but it didn't work. The KiwiColor.xaml is an example, I just want to learn how to make it work

Comment: The KiwiColor.xaml has been posted. There is no error reported in this file.

Comment: I want to create multiple projects that use the same color and theme, so I want the KiwiColor.xaml to be used by all projects

Comment: The demo project is set to dll, and the error exists. If I set the demo project to exe, the error is gone.I added the details to the question. But I don't know why.