# How to reference/use Resource between multiple projects inside solution

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, xaml

I create a solution with 3 projects

ClassLibrary1(WPF Custom Control Library)

```
MyButton.xaml
MyColor.xaml
```

ClassLibrary2(WPF App, Output type : Class Library)

```
MyWindow.xaml
```

WpfApplication(WPF App, Output type : Windows Application)

```
MainWindow.xaml
```

MainWindow starts MyWindow, and MyWindow create a Button which uses the color(mygreen) in MyColor.xaml

And VS reports : The resource "mygreen" could not be resolved.

But in MainWindow, it works ok.

How should I reference resource in ClassLibrary2 from ClassLibrary1??

I hope I described my question correctly.

***New Question:
If the WpfApplication change into a WinForm Application. My answer doesn't work anymore.***

Comment: Here is a link to the related question I created:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75385208/wpf-how-to-reference-color-resources-in-other-projects

Comment: Did you add a project reference from ClassLibrary2 to ClassLibrary1? Can you please add the defiition of MyColor and how you try to reference it in the button?

Answer (score 0):

I find the answer:

1.right click on ClassLibrary2

2.select the item as follows:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/igiOS.png)

3.select the MyColor.xaml the click the "Add As Link":
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dOfTY.png)

4.Add the MyColor.xaml in App.xaml

5.If I use StaticResource mygreen. The vs reports error still, but complies and runs well.
If I use DynamicResource mygreen, the error is gone and everything goes well.

Question:
I have no idea about how to add the folder(including MyButton.xaml and MyColor.xaml) as a link.

This answer works in my demo solution, but not in the solution I'm working on. I'm looking into why

Answer (score 0):

You should add reference the projects you want to use into the entry point project.

Or create a nuget package out dll if you're creating something is to compete with mahapps metro.

To avoid circular references you need to think about what references what and what your theme these brushes form is exactly.

In my simple experiment, my wpf exe references both a usercontrol library which has a brush in it and a custom control library with the control which did not reference that brush.

The exe references both projects, uses the brush and of course it all works fine.

Custom controls are intended to allow for theming. Where you have (say) dark brushes for dark theme and light for light.
The themes can each provide templates and their brushes might be hard coded but are at least within the theme project OR you can have one template which references abstracted brushes.

Where you are essentially just switching out brushes for theming you would have default values within a resource dictionary in the theme project.

Instead of referencing both dll from the entry point you could potentially reference a brushes dll from both the custom library and the entry point.

If you're not using those brushes in the custom library that's a bit pointless.